# Chrome: how to load a custom page at startup by specifying a cmd switch?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line

I'm trying to load my own page, by default, at the startup of Chrome browser. I've read the some posts about Chromium Command Line Switches, but failed to find such a switch to specify a url, any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no switch, it's the default parameter.

`/path/to/chrome "http://stackoverflow.com"`

Comment: It should also work just as `chrome "http://www.superuser.com` assuming your installed properly added chrome to the environment variables.

Comment: I found --instant-url work

Answer (score 0):

[options] are optional because they are in square brackets, so is a [url]. Meaning you can start chrome without specifying any options or a url, or you can give it a url to open.

use `man google-chrome` to read about the browser.

```
google-chrome(1)                  USER COMMANDS                  google-chrome(1)



NAME
       google-chrome - the web browser from Google


SYNOPSIS
       google-chrome [OPTION] [PATH|URL]


DESCRIPTION
       See the Google Chrome help center for help on using the browser.

              

       This manpage only describes invocation, environment, and arguments.
(...)
```